# How can I do a command like this in Notepad ++

Tags: notepad++

Basically I have thousands of separate titles, they end with something like:
  - Graphite, Graphite",Hotpoint

To combat this and make the title start with Graphite Hotpoint, I do this:

```
Find    ^(.*) - Graphite, Graphite",Hotpoint$
Replace Graphite Hotpoint \1"
```

This is great as it sorts these ones out, however I have all the commands wrote down, and it takes forever to individually do it for each colour/brand. Is there a way I can somehow submit all of them to find `/` replace. Rather than going through them all the time.

Basically to simply things. I wouldnt have to do find `/` replace for `^(.*) - Graphite, Graphite",Hotpoint$`   and then find and replace for   `^(.*) - White, White",Hotpoint$`, and then on and on and on, I have them all wrote so I could somehow insert all the commands into notepad++ and then they would all be done.

Comment: Could you please show some sample input lines and the wanted result?

Comment: Basically I need to do the find and replace for things like this below:

^(.*) - White, White",AEG$
White AEG \1"

^(.*) - White, White",Beko$
White Beko \1"

^(.*) - White, White",Bosch$
White Bosch \1"

^(.*) - White, White",Grundig$
White Grundig \1"

^(.*) - White, White",Haier$
White Haier \1"

^(.*) - White, White",Hoover$
White Hoover \1"

^(.*) - White, White",Hotpoint$
White Hotpoint \1"

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Python programming language to solve this issue. Here is a [Python Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/) plug in for Notepad++. For automating your find and replace writing a small script to complete it for you will save you lots of time. [Here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/forums/forum/1199074/topic/4667045) is an example of using regex.

Looks like this could be what you're after:

```
editor.rereplace(r"^([A-Z]{3,5})--\1", r"CODE: \1")
```

Link in comments because I don't have enough rep

You could use a dictionary to store the regex to find with the regex to replace it with

As far as I am aware there is no way natively to achieve what you are asking.

Comment: Hi, I have never used that python script plug before. I am not the best at these sort of things, so if I put it on, where can I learn more, like for example to still be able to setup things the way I would like them to work?

Comment: http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/ will be useful to get you started with using this plug in. For learning python, http://www.learnpython.org/. Check out edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

Find what: `^(.*) - (\w+), \w+",(\w+)$`
Replace with: `$2 $3 $1`

You may want to use `.+`  instead of `\w+`  if there are other characters than `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`