# How can I run this operation in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

thanks for your reply. I should have been more informative. They are not all Product 1, Product 2 etc. Does this make any difference, here is real 4 examples:

IWC61451S Washing Machine - White, White",Beko
IWC61651S Washing Machine - White, White",Hotpoint
IWSC61051 ECO Washing Machine - White, White",Samsung
IWSC61251 ECO Washing Machine - White, White",Sony

and what to change to:

White Beko IWC61451S Washing Machine"
White Hotpoint IWC61651S Washing Machine"
White Samsung IWSC61051 ECO Washing Machine"
White Sony IWSC61251 ECO Washing Machine"

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do a command like this in Notepad ++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25123662/how-can-i-do-a-command-like-this-in-notepad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the pattern provided by you, this should help

`Find What --> (Product .*)( - )(White)(,)( )(White)(")(,)(.*)`

Replace With --> \3 \9 \1\7

[image]

**EDIT** - Based on updated query

`Find What --> (.*)( - )(White)(,)( )(White)(")(,)(.*)`

Replace With --> \3 \9 \1\7

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have edited the original post, can you give me solution for that one please.

Comment: @shaunybhoy - see my updated answer. This would work for both the patterns

Comment: That's brilliant Pankaj, you just helped me out massively ;) I tried to upvote your answer but my reputation is too small. I really appreciate ;)

Comment: Happy to help. Don't forget to mark it as [**Accepted**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)